# Nagios3 crashes with SIGSEGV

Tags: 10.04, server, nagios3

I installed nagios3 on ubuntu server 10.04.1. It was working fine.

Today, I found it stopped and when I tried to start it using `sudo /etc/init.d/nagios3 start`, it did not start. I found this in the log file:

```
Nagios 3.2.0 starting... (PID=11729)
Local time is Wed Dec 22 14:15:31 2010
Caught SIGSEGV, shutting down...
```

I tried to remove and re-install it without success. After googling, it seems that no one has a solution for this. I don't want to install it from source unless it is really the last hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a couple of [cases](http://forums.meulie.net/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=5348&start=0) of [people](http://www.mail-archive.com/nagios-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg32829.html) with this problem.

No-one seems to have reported a bug though - I would suggest you do this by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `ubuntu-bug nagios3`. This will greatly increase the chance that the Ubuntu nagios maintainers will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

From the crash stacktrace I managed to work out that this is related to the Nagios update checking code. As a workaround, you can disable the update check, and Nagios should then work as normal (at least it does for me!). i.e. in `/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg` set

```
check_for_updates=0
```

I've added the stacktrace and workaround to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nagios3/+bug/693372?comments=all).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not try it! I have already re-installed a fresh ubuntu server. Installing nagios3 from source code did not fix the problem.